# Rigibody2D remove push-power

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, physics

I have a player's prefab. The game is online, so when the player joins I place this prefab on the map. There are other players on the map. The player himself is controlled by Rigibody2D component through changing velocity. The problem is that when two players collide (they are created from the same prefab) they push away from each other. I can't disable the collision in collision matrix because I need to prevent one player from going through the other, but I don't need this pushback between the two prefabs. That said, I can't set the mass to 1000 because that would increase the mass of all the players and not result in a result.
What options do I have?

Comment: What should happen when 2 players are colliding with each other?

Comment: This may have to do with the PhysicMaterial used on the colliders. Try creating a new PhysicMaterial and set bounciness to 0. Look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PhysicMaterial.html)